# Cannot modify a CSS with #ID

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

To start with that is how my sort of menu looks like at the moment.

[image]

The problem is that border lines in dsasdf div nor this background should be seen.

[image]

My current HTML code is:

```
<div id='cr'>
        <div>
            NEWS
            <div id="m_news">dfadf</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS for the #cr:

```
  div#cr{

    /*background-color:#1a0f08;*/
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
    width:260px;
    height:100%;
}
div#cr div{
    background-image:url("../img/bg_post.jpg");
    background-position:0px -5px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-radius:2px;
    color:#663b20;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:80px;
    padding:8px;
}
div#cr div:hover{
    border:1px solid #bd8100;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

And the CSS for the #m_news:

```
div#m_news{
background-image:url("../img/menu/messages.gif");
border:0;
}
```

The problem is that **m_news** ID is unable to modify the CSS set by the #cr previously even though it was more like a general page modify.
I have tried searching an answer to this issue on the Internet but as far as I could find is that it sometimes depends on the position of your CSS code, but I tried changing order and it isn't working neither.

Why is **div#cr div more important** than the **div#m_news**?

Also, not to set IDs, how could I set CSS in the most inside DIV?
I mean,
[image]

How could I set new CSS to the smallest box from **#id1** but without modifying the other big one?

Comment: why use `div#m_news`? Why not just `#m_news`? Id is unique anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div#cr div` has a higher precedence than `div#m_news`. You could change it to `div#cr div#m_news`.

You can read more about the *specificity* on this page: [Understanding Style Precedence in CSS: Specificity, Inheritance, and the Cascade](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

You can see that the precedence is ordered like this:

- Element, Pseudo Element: *0,0,0,1*
- Class, Pseudo class, Attribute: *0,0,1,0*
- Id: *0,1,0,0*
- Inline Style: *1,0,0,0*

So according to this:

`div#cr div` has a specificity of *0,1,0,2* whereas `div#m_news` has one of "only" *0,1,0,1*.

Comment: What do you mean by `div#cr div has a higher order than div#m_news` has a higher order?

Comment: @Rov "Precedence" is actually the right word to say - it simply didn't came to my mind so quickly. I added an explanation. Hope this helps.